# Linux: limits on password length

Tags: linux, security, password

I remember a time when Unix passwords (or was it usernames)
could be no longer than 8 or 16 characters. Even nowadays,
the password box displayed by login managers is relatively
narrow, although one can type past its edge. I would like
to know, are there currently any limits to the length of
a password one may enter in a password box under Linux?

Thanks,

John Goche

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you're using, but most modern distros have moved to something other than stock crypt for passwords and can go to much longer lengths. It is still somewhat [distro-dependent](http://www.ratliff.net/blog/2007/09/20/password-length/) though.

- Blowfish-backed systems can do 60 or 72 characters, and probably longer
- MD5-backed systems can to that or more
- SHA1-backed systems aren't that common but do go greatly past 8-char
- SHA2-backed systems are very new and have even fewer restrictions

What's unclear to me is the impact of 2-byte and 4-byte character-sets on these limits.

Generally, if the system was build in the last 3 or so years it can take longer than 8 characters.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I could not find an exact value under https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/user-management.html but at least the password I entered which is relatively long, seems to have all its characters accepted (if I type less characters then the password is not recognized). On older systems, password characters past the 8th character could be anything and the password would be accepted anyways. Very bad!